# Draw a String at the upper right corner of an Image

Tags: c#, image, graphics

I want to get Point X and Y values so that I can draw a String on the upper right corner. I am doing it:

```
string str = "A quick brown fox is absent";
pointX = Convert.ToInt32(img.Width - str.Length);
pointX = pointX - 20; //so that I have 20 pixels after the string
pointY = 20; // 20 pixels from the top
```

The resulting Image is:

[image]

But I want this:

[image]

(though the string isn't clear, edited with Paint)

Any help is appreciated.

Update:

```
font: Calibri
size: 20
```

Edit my code or example code is needed.

Comment: You need to calculate not the length of the string, but the width of the text when rendered in a given font and at a given point size.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Graphics.MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx) instead of `str.Length`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what LB suggested, you should look into both [StringAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringalignment.aspx#Y651) and [LineAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformat.linealignment.aspx).  Check that out.